# regex not being called repeatedly for multiple matches (isn't global)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/g` to do a global look up of all user names that are mentioned.

Here is some sample code.

```
var userRegex = /@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/g;
var text = "This is some sample text @Stuff @Stuff2 @Stuff3";
text.replace(userRegex, function(match, text, urlId) {
    console.log(match);
});
```

So basically that `console.log` only gets called once, in this case it'll just show `@Stuff3`. I'm not sure why it isn't searching globally. If someone can help fix up that regex for me, that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` means "Assert the position at the end of the string (or before a line break at the end of the string, if any)". But you don't seem to want that.

So remove the `$` and use `/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g` instead.

```js
var userRegex = /@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g,
    text = "This is some sample text @Stuff @Stuff2 @Stuff3";
text.match(userRegex); // [ "@Stuff", "@Stuff2", "@Stuff3" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't doing a global search throughout the entire context simply because of the end of string `$` anchor (*which only asserts at the end of string position*). You can use the following here:

```
var results = text.match(/@\w+/g) //=> [ '@Stuff', '@Stuff2', '@Stuff3' ]
```

**Note:** `\w` is shorthand for matching any word character.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Oriol's answer. You can add word boundaries to be more specific.

```
@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b
```

the `\b` will cause the username to match only if it is followed by a non-word character.

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE9uT4/1).